# Access the article edit page from the web address bar?

Tags: links

I have a link online: https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-comments-form-in-wordpress/

On the browser, from the address bar, what syntax, prefix, and suffix do I need to add to the above online link, to be able to access this post edit page (I have admin rights).

I don’t want to use the Edit Button, because then I will have to go online. I mean I just want from a known link, I want to access the post edit page.

Comment: can you add more context for this? What you're asking for isn't possible without writing PHP code, but that doesn't mean your original problem that lead you to this can't be solved. Also keep in mind this is not a discussion forum, you need to be able to mark an answer as not just a nice reply, but as the official correct answer for all people who have your question

Answer (score 2):

> On the browser, from the address bar, what syntax, prefix, and suffix do I need to add to the above online link, to be able to access this post edit page (I have admin rights).

**None, no such prefixes/suffixes/additions exist.** It's not possible out of the box to do this.

**To do this you would need to know the ID of the post to generate the edit URL, and your URL does not contain a post ID.**

Edit links take this form in standard WordPress:

```
wp-admin/post.php?post={POST ID GOES HERE}&action=edit
```

E.g.

```
wp-admin/post.php?post=123&action=edit
```

They can also be filtered by plugins, so a theme or plugin may not use that format.

If you want to be able to take any URL and turn it into an edit URL using only that URL, you will need to write additional code that redirects the user to the edit page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, I also searched Google in many ways, but I couldn't find a solution.

My problem is: If you only edit 10 posts, when you go online to click on EDIT BUTTON , there will be no problem in this case.
But if I have 1000 articles to edit, then having to find the id of 1000 posts before accessing, that's the problem.

Comment: That's an interesting problem, or a discussion, but that's not the question you asked, I can only write answers for the specific question you wrote.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/407898/224273

Comment: @Redpoo this isn't a forum, it's a Q&A site, and these are attempts at answering your question, not replies in a discussion. I understand you have a problem to solve, but people here can only write answers for the question you asked. If you have follow up questions you need to write a _new_ question. If my answer is the answer to the question you asked consider marking it the correct answer by clicking the tick under the voting controls